# Computing bipartite matching of size $k$?

Tags: computational-complexity, perfect-matchings, bipartite-graphs

Given a bipartite graph with $n$ vertices on each side and an integer $k$, how can we compute all bipartite matchings of size $k$?

The problem of computing all perfect matchings is #P-complete. But I am wondering if fixing $k$ can help.

If not, for what values of $k$ the problem is tractable?

Comment: Hmm, if $k=n$ then we're back to the #P-complete problem. If $k$ is a constant, we can check each subset of $k$ edges to see if it's a matching, in polynomial time roughly (# edges$)^k$.